# Kronecker delta on tetrad: two ways leads to two different results?

Tags: gravitational-waves, perturbation-theory, linear-algebra

I'm new here. I'm reading https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.12469, and I'm trying to prove that

\begin{equation}
B \doteq 2 \delta_{a}^{\nu} [\Box E^{a}_{\nu} - \partial^{\mu}\partial_{\nu}E^{a}_{\mu}] = \Box E 
\end{equation}

where the tetrad field is such that $e^{a}_{\mu} = \delta^{a}_{\mu} + E^{a}_{\mu}$, and where $E = \delta^{\mu}_{a} E^{a}_{\mu}$.

It seems quite easy, but I tried in two different ways and I get two different (wrong) results.

1. $ B = 2 \Box (\delta^{\nu}_{a}E^{a}_{\nu}) - 2 \delta^{\nu}_{\mu}\delta^{\mu}_{a} \partial^{\mu} \partial_{\nu} E^{a}_{\mu} = 2 \Box E - 2 \delta^{\nu}_{\mu} \partial^{\mu} \partial_{\nu} (\delta^{\mu}_{a} E^{a}_{\mu}) = 2 \Box E - 2 \delta^{\nu}_{\mu} \partial^{\mu} \partial_{\nu} E  = 2 \Box E - 2 \Box E = 0. $
2. $ B = 2 \Box (\delta^{\nu}_{a}E^{a}_{\nu}) - 2\delta^{\nu}_{a} (\dfrac{\delta^{a}_{\mu} \delta^{\mu}_{a}}{4}) \partial^{\mu} \partial_{\nu} E^{a}_{\mu} = 2 \Box E - \dfrac{1}{2}\delta^{\nu}_{\mu} \partial^{\mu}\partial_{\nu} (\delta^{\mu}_{a} E^{a}_{\mu}) = 2 \Box E - \dfrac{1}{2} \Box E = \dfrac{3}{2} \Box E .$

Pratically, in 1. I used $\delta^{\nu}_{a} = \delta^{\nu}_{\mu} \delta^{\mu}_{a}$, while in 2. I multiplied and divided by 4.
Why do I never get the correct result ($\Box E$) ?? Where I am wrong? Please help me :(

Comment: I do not really get the notation $\delta^{\mu}_{a}$. Are you sure that it is a Kronecker-symbol? Because $\mu$ is a spacetime index and hence ranges from $0$ to $3$ whereas $a$ in the tetrad is the internal index, which labels the different vector fields $\{e^{a}\}$ in the local frame and ranges from $1$ to $4$.

Comment: It's not really a Kronecker symbol. It's the coefficients of the tetrad basis $e_a$ with respect to the coordinate-induced basis $e_\mu.$

Comment: ok, it makes sense. But so, how can I get $\Box E$ as result?

Answer (score 1):

The general relation you cite,
\begin{equation}
B \doteq 2 \delta_{a}^{\nu} [\Box E^{a}_{\nu} - \partial^{\mu}\partial_{\nu}E^{a}_{\mu}] = \Box E 
\end{equation}
is Eq. (28) in the linked paper.  The result you're trying to prove, $B = \Box E$, is equivalent to Eq. (52) in the linked paper, which (the authors note) *only holds in harmonic gauge*,
$$
\partial^\mu \left( E_{\mu \nu} - \frac12 \eta_{\mu \nu} E \right) = 0.
$$
(See Eq. (50) of the linked paper;  the authors appear to use "Lorentz gauge" and "harmonic gauge" interchangeably.)
In particular, in this gauge, we have
\begin{align*}
\partial_\nu \partial^\mu (E_{\mu}^a \delta_a^\nu) &= \partial^\nu \partial^\mu E_{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{2} \partial^\nu \partial^\mu \left( \eta_{\mu \nu} E \right) = \frac{1}{2} \Box E,
\end{align*}
and thus in this gauge
$$
B = 2 \left[ \Box E - \frac{1}{2} \Box E \right] = \Box E.
$$

As far as where your derivations went wrong:  in both your calculations, you inserted $\mu$ as a dummy index and then proceeded to contract each of these $\mu$'s with a *different* pair of $\mu$'s that were already in the expression as dummy indices.  **Do not do this.**  Whenever you insert a new pair of dummy indices, they should use a *different* symbol than any of the already existing indices (dummy or free) in the expression.  In the first derivation, you should have used the substitution $\delta^\nu_a = \delta^\nu_\sigma \delta^\sigma_a$;  in the second, you should have used the identity $\delta^b_\sigma \delta_b^\sigma = 4$.  Of course, neither version would have allowed you to make progress on this derivation, but at least your expressions would still have been correct.